# "catchup=False" is not working in Apache Airflow 2.2.2 | AWS MWAA

Tags: python, cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

As I got to know from Airflow documentation that **Airflow runs jobs at the end of an interval, not the beginning. This means that the first run of your job is going to be after the first interval.** However, My requirement is to run the job at the start of interval itself.

Now as per the recommendation from various documentation/public forums, I have tried to set start date “one day before the actual start date (For testing purpose, I have also tried by setting hardcoded start date to some past date)” and I am setting the “catchup=False” in python Dag definition.

And I have observed that, **for the first-time dag is running for one extra job occurrence**

Example: -
On **2022-04-05 18:53 UTC (YYYY-MM-DD)** I have created one DAG and scheduled it to run at 19:00UTC everyday with start date **2022-04-04 00:00:00** (one day before) and it had trigger first scheduled job just after it got rendered on AWS MWAA UI, i.e exactly at **2022-04-05 18:57 UTC** (**catchup=False** was set) and job got trigger again at **19:00UTC** (which was expected).

Hence it is looks like "catchup=False" is not working properly.

Please help me understanding the mistake here. Thanks.!!

DAG Code:-

```
import time
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True
}
def add_sleep(**kwargs):
    print("operator called")
    time.sleep(5)

with DAG(
        dag_id="airflow_scheduler_poc",
        description='Airflow scheduler Test',
        start_date=datetime.strptime("2022-04-04 00:00:00",'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        end_date= None,
        schedule_interval="00 19 * * *",
        is_paused_upon_creation = False,
        catchup=False,
        tags=['emr'],
) as dag:

    job_flow_1 = PythonOperator(task_id="job_flow_1", python_callable=add_sleep, op_kwargs={})
    job_flow_2 = PythonOperator(task_id="job_flow_2", python_callable=add_sleep, op_kwargs={})
                                            
    job_flow_1 >> job_flow_2
```

Comment: "My requirement is to run the job at the start of interval itself." - Check timetables in Airflow documntation.

Comment: @EladKalif As per best of my understanding for that we need to write custom timetables in airflow plugins. Here in our product we are trying to build user customizable scheduler feature for daily, weekly(selected days in week), monthly & yearly schedules, which may lead to create separate custom timetables for every scheduled DAG and as we are using Airflow on top the of AWS MWAA, updating plugins means updating MWAA environment which will add 10-15min of downtime for every update.  So looking for other options. Feel free to correct me if My understanding is wrong somewhere. Thanks..!!

Comment: Airflow provide scheduler and instructions how to make it work. You wish to customize a complex core component in an easy and effortless manner... This is alot to ask.

Comment: @EladKalif Hey, I can understand that actual problem statement is complex however here I am trying to understand why the scheduler job is getting called just after it created even though "catchup" is set as false.

Comment: what are the execution date of those 2 jobs?